# dremel tool adapter thingy that holds cutting disc what is it called

Tags: dremel

what is the silver adapter thingy called
I have lost the one I brought from clas ohlson.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dremel specifically calls them a mandrel. You could also search cutoff wheel arbor for some larger sizes.

See photo below from Amazon.

[image]

Comment: Searching for dremel silver adapter thingy finds it also in images.

Comment: @crip659  I've  come to the conclusion that "thingy"  really does cover a lot of strange parts.